# How To Do MySQL Data Actions in A Function With PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My php version is 5.6.11.
I'm using PDO for mysql actions.
I'll use functions for select any data from my database. Like this;

```
function select_post($id) {
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?');
$result->execute(array($id));
return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Then I tried include my connnection file in function. It worked. But do I have to include this file to all of my functions ? Or do we have a different solution for this problem ?

My working code is this;

```
function select_post($id) {
require "config.php";
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM eb_settings WHERE setid = ?');
$result->execute(array($id));
return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: You have a variable scope issue - `$db` isn't in scope inside `select_post`. You need to either pass it in as an extra parameter, or add it as a `global`

Comment: How can i add it as global ? The $db variable is in config.php file. I including config.php into functions file but it doesnt work.

Comment: You need to include `config.php` at the start of your code; and inside your function, a line of `global $db;`. That will let you use the `$db` variable inside a function

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.

Answer (score -1):

The best is to use a connexion.php file that you'll include at the beginning of every file where you'll proceed to a database connexion. This way you'll only have to change the information at one place if the password or the username changes for example.